# Plot titles using lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, title

I'm plotting a list of data frames.

These are the names of the data frames:

```
names(meltmean)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

I used this to plot:

```
stacked<-lapply(meltmean, 
                function (x) ggplot(x, aes(x=month, y= value, fill=Type))+geom_area()+ggtitle(names(meltmean)))
```

I want to get the title of each data frame in each plot, but for all I'm just getting the first name. So in all plots the title is "A".

I also tried with `+ ggtitle(names(x))` but with that I get the name of the first column of each data frame, not the name of the data frame.

What do I need to change so I get the correct name in each plot?

Comment: I tried that but the title I get is the name of the first column of each data frame, not the name of the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
stacked <- lapply(names(meltmean), 
                function (x) ggplot(meltmean[[x]], aes(x=month, y= value, fill=Type))+geom_area()+ggtitle(x))
```